# GeoGoogle - Google Geocoder Java API deprecated?

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

Is this project deprecated now?

I got a 404 Error checking the examples:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html#Geocoding_Examples

Comment: See here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have moved to a different location: [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding)

Comment: that's what i thought, but i miss all the classes, the package is not anymore geo.google.* , but com.google.maps.*

Comment: Packages? I think you'll need to explain better which API you're looking for. And code.google.com has been closed down for code hosting.